# How to convert JSON into rows in Postgres stored procedure

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql, stored-procedures

I am trying to write stored procedure in Postgres. But I have data as JSON in Postgres like the below.

```
{
    "identifiers": 
        [
            {
                "identifierType": "VIN",
                "value": "L608"
            },
            {
                "identifierType": "VIN",
                "value": "L604"
            }
       ]
```

Now I need to convert the above JSON into separate columns and rows using Postgres:

```
identifierType        value
-----------------------------
  VIN                  L608
  VIN                  L604
```

Please help! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need for a stored procedure to do this.  In fact, a stored procedure couldn't return those data, although a function could.

Here's an example to return this data from a query:

```
-- Set up the test data
CREATE TABLE test (data json);

INSERT INTO test VALUES ('{"identifiers": 
 [
            {
                "identifierType": "VIN",
                "value": "L608"
            },
            {
                "identifierType": "VIN",
                "value": "L604"
            }
]}');


SELECT "identifierType", value 
FROM test
CROSS JOIN json_to_recordset(data->'identifiers') as x("identifierType" text, value text);
```

Here's a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=cfbec5a1ed22b7390e84a976b1d57ae5).

EDIT:

Here's a function that can do this.  Note the a procedure will not work because you can't return data from a procedure.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION convert_my_json(p_data json)
RETURNS TABLE (
  "identifierType" text,
  "value" text
)
AS $$
  SELECT * FROM json_to_recordset(p_data->'identifiers') as x("identifierType" text, value text);
$$
LANGUAGE SQL
IMMUTABLE;
```

Updated [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=ebba07a05dd0c7dc78250ebc4aa6dd29).

Comment: And a link to the manual: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html

Comment: is there a way to create a stored procedure for this and call the procedure?

Comment: @pavithra I updated the answer and the fiddle with an example function.

Comment: @Jeremy is it possible to use these retrieved JSON columns to my select query inside the same function?  query 1 : select json_to_recordset   query 2   :    select query with columns retrieved from query 1. ( I want to use both query 1 and query 2 in same function, but  return the result from query 2)

Comment: Probably?  It would be better to open a new question and include the results you are trying to get.  I can't tell from your description what you are trying to accomplish.